# My recursive function to reverse the chars of a string does not work

Tags: c++, string, recursion, function-definition

I was trying to make different recursive functions for the same problem i.e. to reverse the letters of a word. While all my solutions with a void return type (where i just printed letters in reverse) worked, I've been trying to make one using the string return type but am running into a problem. When entered hello, the following code gives me l. And I can't seem to figure out why...

```
string reverse(string s)
{
    int len = s.length();
    if (len <= 1)
    {
        return s;
    }
    swap(s[0], s[len-1]);
    return reverse(s.substr(1, len-2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling your function with a substring each time and only returning the final character. In your lower return statement ( return reverse(s.substr(1, len-2)); ) you need to include the first and last characters as well.

Something like:
return s[0] + reverse(s.substr(1,len-2)) + s[len-1];

Comment: Here is a working example: https://onlinegdb.com/dNCQAP9SB

Answer (score 0):

The word "Hello" has an odd number of letters. So the last recursive call of the function returns the letter 'l' due to this if statement

```
if (len <= 1)
{
    return s;
}
```

that is the return value of all the recursive calls of the function.

You should write at least like

```
string reverse(string s)
{
    auto len = s.length();
    if (len <= 1)
    {
        return s;
    }
    swap(s[0], s[len-1]);
    return s[0] + reverse(s.substr(1, len-2)) + s[len-1];
}
```

In fact using the function swap is redundant. You could write

```
string reverse(string s)
{
    return s.length() < 2 ? s 
                          : s[s.length() - 1] + reverse( s.substr( 1, s.length() - 2 ) ) + s[0];
}
```

Without the recursion the function can look for example the following way

```
string reverse( const string &s )
{
    return { s.rbegin(), s.rend() };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use this code as to get some proper logic. I am passing string and its 0th index and its last index as parameters. Then just used the swapping technique and made a recursive call. For better understanding i will recommend debug the code and watch every itration.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string reverse(string str, int i, int j)
{
    if (i >= j)
        return str;
    char temp = str[i];
    str[i] = str[j];
    str[j] = temp;
    return reverse(str, i + 1, j - 1);
}

int main()
{
    string str = "Hello";
    cout << "Reverse string is: " << reverse(str, 0, str.length() - 1);
    return 0;
}
```